# ggplot: edit shape of points based on second column

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal is to plot a map with dwelling locations as points, where points are divided into two colours, based on a categorical variable, name `category`. Of those dwellings, a few dwellings need to have a different shape, e.g., a star. The column that describes this is called `star` in the example below. My dataframe looks like this:

| x | y | category | star |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | 1 | 0 |
| 143 | 556 | 0 | 0 |
| 124 | 556 | 1 | 1 |
| 233 | 256 | 1 | 0 |

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color=category)) +
  geom_point()
```

The code above gives me what I need, except for the 'stars'. How can distinguish this second column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have assumed you want the points with `star` with a value of 1 to be a star shape.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = x, y = y, color=factor(category), shape = factor(star))) +
  geom_point(size = 8) +
  scale_shape_manual(breaks = c(0, 1),
                     values = c(1, 11))+
  labs(color = "Category",
       shape = "Star")
```

data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(123L, 143L, 124L, 233L), 
                      y = c(456L, 556L, 556L, 256L), 
                      category = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
                      star = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>